# Margin top responsive footer

Tags: html, css

I wants to move all the way down #footer

If you use the `"top margin: X value"`  footer down but the resolution of the laptop ... scroll bar appears on the right

This is css code:

```
    #footer
{ 
  text-align: center;
  border:0px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  background:url(img/BODY-MENU.png);
 margin:0px;
bottom:0px;
}
```

What should I use for the footer to be responsive?

This is the link:

http://test.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this to it:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

This will fix it to the bottom of the window, so no matter your screen size it will be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To place the footer at the bottom you should give your footer a fixed or absolute position.